# Encryption decryption Throws Error some time and some time works

Tags: apex, visualforce, java

Encription Decription Throws Error Some time.
Comman pattern that fails is Encripted Text text to decript is when i am passing in encripted text into URL and if URL contains % or + it throws Error.

**Encripted text** - throws Error while decription. Using Encription with  Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', cryptoKey , data );

```
k2vAafArfVvfbITPdKLvtCVHsa/M+84/R/rcXjEBlVQA14sqspntuQn0mKDiaPdL 

Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

Comment: I am Passing the Encoded string in URL. So please share That works with URL Encoding and Decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try EncodingUtil Class to encode the encrypted string before passing in URL. Also there is a decode method is available to decode the encoded string.

```
String encodedString = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(encryptedString,'UTF-8');
String decodedString = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(encodedString ,'UTF-8');
```